# A question about type of electrical connector

Tags: connector, screw-terminal

I have some electronics equipment inside an enclosure and at some point many ground and supply wires needs to be joint.

Focusing on the blue wires in the below photo, I soldered three wires on both sides and joint them with a terminal connector.

[image]

But I'm not happy with both the reliability and outlook. Is there any connector type to join multiple wires at a single node? I found some buses but they are for very high voltages and big.

Comment: Im curious how could that be done and used for more professional satble way/look.

Comment: The soldering is definitely a bad idea for many reasons. Do you want to keep wires separate or keep them joined together without soldering and still use the terminal block in the picture, or also get rid of the terminal block? You could just use ferrules for terminating single wires or multiple wires together for a reliable terminal block connection.

Comment: _in the below photo_. What photo?

Comment: I've re-added the removed picture. If you need to update it please do.

Answer (score 12):

You should never solder wires and insert them into a screw connector like this, as the solder may cold flow (not 100% sure this term is correct in English) causing a bad connection over time.

Depending on the application, there are many ways of doing this.

You could use something like [Wago 221](https://www.wago.com/global/installation-terminal-blocks-and-connectors/compact-splicing-connector/p/221-415), where you just insert one cable per hole which connects them together:
[image: Wago 221]
These can also easily be re-opened in case you need to modify the connection sometimes.

For a really permanent connection, you could crimp all the wires together with a crimping splice:
[image: Crimped splice]
(Image source: [Efi Hardware](https://www.efihardware.com/products/3117/brass-wiring-splice-crimp-terminal))

Then you put electrical tape, heat shrink tube or similar to insulate it.

Or, if you want to use the type of terminal block you have now, instead of soldering the wires together you could crimp all of them in a single ferrule.
[image: Wire ferrule]
(Image source: [eFixx](https://www.efixx.co.uk/Know%20How/ferrules))

Comment: Wagos can accept multiple cables of appropriate size in a single hole. As can wire nuts and most other connectors. Just follow the manufacturer specs.

Comment: _Wagos can accept multiple cables_ "Wires", not "cables".

Comment: @Passerby I cannot find Wago specifying more than one wire per hole for the 221's. But they do say "Tool-free connection of up to *five stripped, fine-stranded conductors* ", and they have maximum five holes -> One wire per hole. Maybe some other Wago model can handle multiple wires, but I'm pretty sure the 221 does not.